# (PSET5 cs50) Seg Fault while unloading an array of linked lists

Tags: c, linked-list, cs50

this is a part of cs50pset 5 so it is a spoiler. Function suppose to unload appended strings from an array of linked lists, some sort of hash table(I don't know if it is the correct definition). But it seems to create a seg fault. Can you say if this function causes a seg fault or should I check other functions of the problem. Thank you so much for your time.

```
    // Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 1000; // trying to find most optimized N it could be different

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    node* iterf; //forward iteration
    node* iterb; //pointer that stays behind of iterf

    iterf = table[i];
    iterb = iterf;
    while (iterb != NULL)
    {
        iterb = table[i];
        iterf = iterb -> next;
        free(iterb);
        iterb = iterf;
    }
}

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You have a check `if (iterf == NULL)` but then you still continue, dereferencing the pointer with `iterf = iterf -> next;`, even it is a null pointer - that can't be correct

Comment: You have `if (iterf == NULL) { free(iterf); }` which is a complete no-op.  If the pointer is null, freeing it does nothing.  The fact that you go on to use the possibly null pointer doesn't improve things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this loop

```
node* iterf;
node* iterb;

// ...
iterf = table[i];
iterb = iterf;

while (1)
{
    if (iterf == NULL)
    {
        free(iterf);         // <-- Why are you freeing a NULL pointer?
    }
    iterf = iterf -> next;   // <-- iterf CAN be NULL! 
    free(iterb);             
    iterb = iterf;
}                            // How can this be stopped? When it segfaults?
```

It's unclear why the outer loop should stop at the first NULL pointer, returning false, but the inner loop should just be a normal singly linked list freeing.

```
node *current = table[i];
while ( current != NULL )
{
    // Now I know that the pointer can be dereferenced
    node *next = current->next;

    // Free it only after saving the next
    free(current);
    current = next;
}
```

Comment: I thought it like if the first pointer in the linked list is null then there is nothing loaded to here. so break for that linked list. But by freeing the pointer I was meant what it points. I will work on that thank you. @Bob__

Comment: Can you check the current form of the code ? @Bob__

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution at the moment I deleted the //THIS LINE double iteration goes away. Because due to that line pointers go back to the beginning and try to free a memory that has already freed. At least that is what I figured out. If any comments or addition please write it. Thanks for all the help, it is a luck to have such a helpful community :)

```
    iterf = table[i];
    iterb = iterf;
    while (iterb != NULL)
    {
        iterb = table[i]; // THIS LINE
        iterf = iterb -> next;
        free(iterb);
        iterb = iterf;
    }
```

Comment: The most important thing is that you seem to understand why that line it's wrong (remember, trying to access member `next` of the already freed struct is also an error).

Comment: Thanks for all the help :) @Bob__